# Beamer - error when uncovering tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, errors, overlays, tikz-matrix

I am trying to uncover a tikz matrix using the code below. But it is throwing an "undefined controlled sequence" error. Does anybody know how I can fix this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\uncover<2->{
\matrix (mat) [matrix of nodes]
{
8 & 1 & 6 \\
3 & 5 & 7 \\
4 & 9 & 2 \\
};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe the `overlay-beamer-styles` tikz library could help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this? `beamer-overlay-styles` allows you to uncover any element of a `tikzpicture`, including matrices.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (mat) [matrix of nodes,visible on=<2->]
{
8 & 1 & 6 \\
3 & 5 & 7 \\
4 & 9 & 2 \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility is to use `ampersand replacement`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\uncover<2->{
\matrix (mat) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&]
{
8 \& 1 \& 6 \\
3 \& 5 \& 7 \\
4 \& 9 \& 2 \\
};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you add matrix delimiters, you may be interested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450851/121799).

Comment: Thanks - out of interest, do you know why my method didn't work?

Comment: @Henry No, not really to the extent that I can provide a very good explanation. P.S. If you add delimiters, please look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450851/121799 (the corresponding question has alternative workarounds).